# How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{x-n\sinh^2 x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is what I tried:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{(x-n\sinh^2 x)^k}{k!}\ dx$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{k!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{k}\binom{k}{r}x^r(-n\sinh^2 x)^{k-r}\ dx$$

After this I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: FWIW, I tried $n=1,2,3$ in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex*e%5E%28-3sinh%28x%29%5E2%29+from-infinity+to+infinity) and in each case I got $\sqrt{\frac\pi n}$

Comment: You left out a factor of $(-1)^{k-r}$, but the individual integrals diverge, so this doesn't look like a viable approach.

Comment: ok ,i edited it if it's not  viable approach then how should i proceed

Answer (score 17):

$$\ldots=\int_0^\infty(e^x+e^{-x})e^{-n\sinh^2 x}\,dx\ \underset{\sinh x=y}{\phantom{\big[}=\phantom{\big]}}\ 2\int_0^\infty e^{-ny^2}\,dy=\sqrt{\pi/n}.$$

Comment: Very nice trick.